sum of average value by ordernumber and itemnumber
I have a lot of duplicate lines in my sales value, these lines are the result of a large query breakdown with sublevels. But now I need to calculate the sum of sales by ordernumber and itemnumber, so my output for pepsi would be 18 and for coca cola would be 24.
What is the best solution for this? (see picture below)
example

can you simply drop duplicates and then add the sales ?

If you can't do that, you may be able to use ROW_NUMBER in DAX (supposed to work the same way as it does in T-SQL) where you specify a window that the numbering happens over. Then you just use something like FILTER() to keep only the first instance of each value. And since that returns a table, you can base your measures or whatever on that.

You can use SUMMARIZE() function to summarize your data (I am using your example).

I entered your sample data:



Created new table with the following DAX, which will return the average of the sales by order number and item number:



Now you can SUM your sales without worrying for the duplicates.

Probably instead of doing this summarization in Power BI, you can query your source without the duplicates, but it is up to you how you will solve this.
